# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site

Tags: java, maven

Повторяю пример из книги по maven. Выполняю команду **mvn site** и получаю ошибку:

*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project simple: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site: org/apache/maven/doxia/siterenderer/DocumentContent*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Сам pom файл выглядит следующим образом:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.ch03</groupId>
<artifactId>simple</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>simple</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091539/maven-site-plugins-3-3-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-maven-doxia

Answer (score 1):

Изменила версию плагина maven-site-plugin на 3.7.1 (можно выше), сделала реимпорт проекта maven и все заработало.
Версия плагина в IntelliJ IDEA, несмотря на эти действия, подсвечивала как не найденную, что меня смутило, но после нажатия на кнопку обновления (Ctrl + Alt + Y) все стало нормально.